# How to use flags to record and show 'visited this place' by users on a node type 'destination' in a tourist site?

Tags: flags

This is about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

How can I show under respective node, the count of those users who visited that place(node type is a destination, which acn be flagged as visted/not-visited). Going further, the count should be a link leading to list of users who have visited it.

I have views and flags ready on my install.